# What is meaning of this symbol in definition of Galois Extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, definition

Let F be an extension field of K such that the fixed field of the Galois
group $Aut_K{F}$ is K itself. Then F is said to be a Galois extension (field) of K. THis definition was in my course notes.

> I have seen on this website, a user wrote in answers to my questions in field theory that: " I think your definition of Galois Extension in finite case is $F^{Aut_K {F}} = K$.

The user is inactive for quite some time so,he didn't replied when I asked him:

> What is the meaning of the symbol $F^{Aut_K {F}}$?

So, can you please tell me?

Comment: $A^S$ is often shorthand for the fixed points of $S$ acting on $A$ (in various contexts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of automorphisms of $F$. The set of elements of $F$ fixed by every element of $G$ is called the fixed field of $G$, and is denoted
$$F^G = \{\alpha\in F : \varphi(\alpha) = \alpha\ \text{for all $\varphi\in G$}\}.$$